# Write in Google search bar

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a small jar file which will help the user by opening IE, go to *maps.google.com* and then loading a specific KMZ file.

Opening IE is no problem, here is the program so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class DSI {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start https://maps.google.com");
    }
}
```

how do I print this link* to the Google search bar?

- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2604148/DSI.kmz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you inserting the link directly to the link? Try this:

https://maps.google.de/maps?q=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2604148/DSI.kmz

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a look at some Web Automation software such as selenium.
Using the Firefox plugin you could record what you want to do then export the script as a Java program (if necessary).

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/